# laravel one to many inserting

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many

I have two models: `User` and `Roles`. I need to insert `User` and his `Roles` from same form.

```
$user = new User;
$user ->name = $request ->input('name');
$user ->email = $request ->input ('email');
$user -> password = $request ->input ('pass');
$user ->save();
$role = new Role;
$role ->name = $request ->input('role');
$role ->explain = $request ->input('exp');
$role ->save();
$role ->roles() ->save($user);
```

It gives me an error.

**`User` model:**

```
public function roles()
{
    # code...
    return $this ->hasMany('App\Role');
}
```

**`Role` model:**

```
public function users()
{
    # code...
    return $this ->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**migrations:**

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->text('name');
        $table->string('explain');
        $table->timestamps();
        //cascade
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')-    >onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I think that is the relationship is done correctly.

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`many`.`roles`, CONSTRAINT `roles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `roles` (`name`, `explain`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sss, asw, 2016-02-21 07:34:02, 2016-02-21 07:34:02))

Comment: this is the error and insert into users only

Comment: If a role belongs to only one user, you should probably change your method from 'users()' to 'user()'..... Just a suggestion, not the solution to your problem

Comment: Actually I take that back as Patricus has said it is indeed part of the solution to your problem

Answer (score 15):

Your issue is that you saved your `Role` before you associated it with a user. Since you didn't associate it to a user, your `roles.user_id` field is empty, and that violates your foreign key.

You need to change your code to associate the user before saving the role, as shown below:

```
// create the user
$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->email = $request->input ('email');
$user->password = $request->input ('pass');
$user->save();

$role = new Role;
$role->name = $request->input('role');
$role->explain = $request->input('exp');

// option 1:
// this will set the user_id on the role, and then save the role to the db
$user->roles()->save($role);

// option 2:
// associate the user to the role (sets the user_id field)
// then you need to save your role
$role->users()->associate($user);
$role->save();
```

Use option 1 or option 2, not both.

### Edit

Additionally, when not passed in, the `belongsTo` relationship builds the foreign key based on the name of the relationship function. Since your method is named `users`, it is going to look for the `users_id` field, which is not correct. You will either need to pass in the correct foreign key name as the second parameter, or rename your relationship method from `users()` to `user()`.

```
// option 1
// pass in the foreign key field as the second parameter
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}

// option 2
// rename the relationship to user
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

You can do both, but at the least, it would make the code more logical if you were to rename the method to `user()`.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `roles` (`name`, `explain`, `users_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (admin, an admin, 13, 2016-02-21 13:58:19, 2016-02-21 13:58:19))

Comment: why user_id not found?

Comment: @user5565240 That doesn't make sense based on the relationships you've shown. Is this a one to many or many to many relationship? Can you update your question with your table definitions?

Comment: The error you just copied and pasted says it expects a field 'users_id' are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? Check that you have 'user_id' and not 'users_id'.

Answer (score 3):

this error because you didn't pass the user_id for the roles tables. it is a foreign key in this table and must be passed.
you can save your one to many relation tables in this way:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

firstly you save the master table **user** row, then by `find()` method you can save all details rows in **roles** table like the link example.

```
$role = new Role(array('','','','')); // array of roles row values you want save
$user = User::find(1); // where 1 is id
$role = $user->roles()->save($role );
```

Comment: I need to add them at same time

Comment: ok, what is the problem you can get last_insert_id for user row by this way after insert in user table: $user_id = DB::Query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'); then use it in find function or pass it to role like this: $role ->user_id = $user_id; if you use your code.

Comment: @user5565240 what do you mean add them at the same time?

Comment: I mean I need to insert all data form one form and submit button